# Azure Blob Storage Account in both CDN & Front Door

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-front-door

We have a storage account that has been connected to Azure CDN for some time.

We don't want to disconnect it as traffic is flowing nicely.

However we'd like to also route traffic for a new website through to the same storage account via Azure Front Door.

Is it possible to have 2 endpoints with 2 custom domains for a storage account?

At the moment when I click on 'Use Existing' for Front Door the menu is not populated and I can't move forwards.  However if I create a new storage account this menu populates correctly with the Azure Front door profiles.[image: A]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one default endpoint that is used to access the data, and in your image, you should see the CDN profile, but you need to be aware that both services (CDN and Front door) should be in the same region